# Robocopy: adding maxage argument breaks command

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, robocopy

So I am simply trying to add the /maxage argument to my robocopy command.

This command works just fine:
`robocopy $source $destination *.* /e /zb`

But once I add /maxage it gives me a Invalid Parameter error
`robocopy $source $destination *.* /e /zb /maxage:1825`

I want it so files older than 5 years are not copied over. Am I missing something?
Thank you for your help

I have googled this pretty thoroughly and can't find what I'm missing, but I have to be mistaken on something with this command.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried calculating the date of the day 5 years ago and specifying this?

Comment: Please add a [mcve], so we can see the call in context and try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using the following template to pass arguments with colons in them.

```
  $robocopyOptions = @('/e', '/zb', '/maxage:1825')
  $CmdLine = @($source, $destination) + $robocopyOptions           
  & 'robocopy.exe' $CmdLine
```

Note: I noticed you already had $source & $destination in your code.